# Chakra UI's LinkOverlay not working when nested inside GatsbyLink

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, chakra-ui

I'm trying to wrap a link around a container using LinkBox and LinkOverlay from ChakraUI.

When I try to use LinkOverlay *alone* (using `href`), the code behaves as expected, but when I try to wrap a **GatsbyLink** around it (using the `to` prop to define the destination), as stated by the [Chakra-UI Documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/link-overlay/usage#usage-with-routing-library), the LinkBox stops working.

Here's the code:

```
<Flex {...props}>
   <LinkBox>
    <Image
      as={GatsbyImage}
      image={mainImage?.gatsbyImageData}
      alt={mainImage?.description || 'Article Main Image'}
      height="100px"
    />
    <Flex>
      <Text
        variant={'label'}
        as={GatsbyLink}
        to={`/${category?.slug}`}
        casing="uppercase"
      >
        {category?.title}
      </Text>
      <Link
        variant={'heading'}
        mt={1}
        lineHeight="1.2em"
        as={GatsbyLink}
        to={`/${category?.slug}/${slug}`}
      >
        <LinkOverlay>{title}</LinkOverlay>
      </Link>
    </Flex>
  </LinkBox>
</Flex>
```